# How to print objects except one, without deleting anything (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

So i want to filter object of objects, and print all of them except one, which i specify by key.

```js
const obj = {1: {age: 10}, 2: {age: 20}};

console.log(obj);
```

So i must have option to somehow specify that i don't want the obj[1] to be printed. How do i do that? : |

- I don't want to delete anything from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `filter()` the keys and then convert it back to object using `reduce()`

```js
const obj = {1: {age: 10}, 2: {age: 20}};

let key = 1
console.log(Object.keys(obj).filter(x => x != key).reduce((ac,a) => ({...ac,[a]:obj[a]}),{}));
```

Using the new feature `Object.fromEntries`

```js
const obj = {1: {age: 10}, 2: {age: 20}};

let key = 1
let res = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(x => x[0] != key));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 5):

You could [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the object:

```js
const obj = {1: {age: 10}, 2: {age: 20}, 3: {age: 30}},
      key = 1;
      
const { [key]:_, ...rest } = obj
console.log(rest);
```